# Pandas Table Reshaping

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet in this format with message logs:

```
ID Source Date    Hour Interval Mgs
1  online 1/1/20  0    1        0
1  online 1/1/20  0    2        3
1  online 1/1/20  0    3        1
1  online 1/1/20  0    4        12
1  online 1/1/20  1    1        2
1  online 1/1/20  1    2        1
```

How do I use pandas to transform it to this format?

```
ID          1
Source      1
Date        1/1/20
Hour        0               1 
Interval    1   2   3   4   1   2 
Messages    0   3   1   12  2   1
```

I've tried the following:

```
multi = df.set_index(["ID", "Source", "Date"])
out = multi.T
```

but I got close but not there yet.

```
ID          1
Source      1
Date        1/1/20 1/1/20 1/1/20 1/1/20 1/1/20 1/1/20
Hour        0      0      0      0      1      1 
Interval    1      2      3      4      1      2 
Messages    0      3      1      12     2      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
out = df.set_index(["ID", "Source", "Date",'Hour','Interval']).T
```

Output:

```
ID            1                
Source   online                
Date     1/1/20                
Hour          0            1   
Interval      1  2  3   4  1  2
Mgs           0  3  1  12  2  1
```